# RNGCryptoServiceProvider fail chi-square test on large random numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

Does any one know why the RNGCryptoServiceProvider fail chi-square test when trying to get numbers bigger then 300,000,000.

I tried to get random number in the range 0-1,000,000,000 and the result that I received fail chi-square test, the numbers in the range 0-300,000,000 appeared more than the other numbers.

eventually i combined the big number form to smaller numbers (0-99 *100M + 0-99,999,999) and the chi-square test pass.

can anyone explain this anomaly in big numbers?

I used the following code to get the numbers

```
    [Timeout(TestTimeout.Infinite), TestMethod]
    public void TestMethodStatistic()
    {
        Dictionary<long, long> appearances = new Dictionary<long, long>();
        UInt64 tenBillion = 10000000000;

        for (UInt64 i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            UInt64 random = GetSIngleRandomNumberInternal() % tenBillion;
            UInt64 bucket = random /10000000;

            if (!appearances.ContainsKey(Convert.ToInt64(bucket)))
            {
                appearances.Add(Convert.ToInt64(bucket), 0);
            }
            appearances[Convert.ToInt64(bucket)]++;
        }
        string results = "\nBucket Id\tcount\n";
        foreach (var appearance in appearances)
        {
            results += appearance.Key+"\t"+ appearance.Value +"\n";
        }
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Result.txt",results);
    }

    private RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    private UInt64 GetSIngleRandomNumberInternal()
    {
        byte[] randomNumBytes = new byte[sizeof(UInt64)];
        rngCsp.GetBytes(randomNumBytes);


        return BitConverter.ToUInt64(randomNumBytes, 0);
    }
```

Take the Result.txt file and copy the content to an excel.
make it a table and add 2 columns 1 is the expected result with the value 100000 and the second one is the Chi-square test the value is "=CHISQ.TEST([count],[[expected ]])"

when the value of the chi-square test is less than 0.1 we have a problem.

Comment: Please show your testing code.

Comment: Please edit the complete code into your question - don't use comments, and don't just include a single method.

Comment: You assume that framework code is buggy. It is far more likely that your testing code is wrong. The bug is almost always your bug, not the frameworks.

Comment: but it fail Chi-square test which means that its not Random enough...

Comment: One problem is that you're introducing a bias when you use the remainder technique. See http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/ for an explanation.

Comment: "when the value of the chi-square test is less than 0.1 we have a problem." - the usual value used for statistical significance is 5%, or 0.05. Is there any particular reason you are using 10%? Do you get a similar result every time you run your code?

Comment: I get 0.0 every time.

Comment: Jim you are right!!!
when i changed the parameter tenBillion value to be 2^34 the chi-square test is 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely the problem is that you're introducing a bias when you use the remainder technique. See [How much bias is introduced by the remainder technique?](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/) for an explanation.