# Creating random hash function that returns a set

Tags: python, random, set, sampling

Consider the following code:

```
def xorHash(n):
    mask = random.getrandbits(32)
    def xorIt(x):
        return (hash(x) ^ mask) % n
    return xorIt
```

This returns a random hash function which maps elements into a number in {0,1,...,rng-1}.

I want to create a random hash function that maps each element into exactly `k` elements in {0,1,...,rng-1} (without repetitions). The example above does the job for k=1.

> **What is the most efficient way of creating a random hash function which returns a k-sized random subset of {0,1,...,rng-1}?**

Comment: Don't use `range` as an argument  name. It is  a very important built-in and you shadow it.

Comment: @MikeMüller - changes, thanks.

Comment: Does "without repetitions" mean you want a perfect hash function, or that the `k` elements in [0, rng) are distinct? Have you considered using `k` hash functions (or is the question about how to create those)?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis - yes, I need `k` distinct values. Having `k` hash functions may return duplicates. I can keep more than `k`, and then unique the results, hoping I have `k` distinct values, but this seems inefficient and may fail.

Comment: If you think of a hash function's result as a bitstring, concatenating `k` of them to produce the final hash will not produce duplicates. Its probably not efficient for large `k`, though.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis - I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by thinking of it as a bitstring? hashing into k*log(rng) bits and then thinking of each log(rng) bits as a different element? I can't see why this guarantees no duplicates are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seed an RNG with an ordinary integer-valued randomized hash of your data and use it to draw a random sample from the desired range:

```
def generate_randomized_set_valued_hash_function(n, k):
    hashfunc = generate_randomized_hash_function()
    def set_valued_hashfunc(x):
        rng = random.Random(hashfunc(x))
        return set(rng.sample(xrange(n), k))
    return set_valued_hashfunc
```

What RNG and what integer-valued hash function you choose will depend on how strong and how fast you need your set-valued hash function to be.

Answer (score 0):

if the range is relatively small then you can create an array of your items.
you will make them in a random order by shuffling the items by generating a random and swapping the first with the item at the generated number.

if your range is relatively big you can generate numbers in the full range and if you get an item that is not unique just try again.

by the way your code has an issue that your numbers are probably not unified distributed because you use the % operator. the reminder technique creates a bias for small numbers, you can read more in the following posts:

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879023/rngcryptoserviceprovider-fail-chi-square-test-on-large-random-numbers)

[How much bias is introduced by the remainder technique](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/16/how-much-bias-is-introduced-by-the-remainder-technique/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `%` works for me as I hash IPV4 addresses (32 bits) into the range {0,1,...,255}, hence no bias is created. I need to get a 64-sized random subset of the range for each element, and this seems quite costly to save explicitly (mainly if I need multiple such hash functions).

Comment: sounds like a small range of numbers so I think that you should shuffle a closed set of numbers.
how many times do you need to generate it?

Comment: Depends on the input. 
I start with a single hash and add additional if there exists

Comment: both will work quit good but the closed set and swapping will have better time performance so unless you have a real memory limitations go with that one.